# how do I calculate the points in a 5-point polygon

Tags: java, swing

I have a class Demo with a button and when the user clicks the button called polygon a polygon is drawn starting from the point where they hit, The code works fine in drawing but unfortunately it draws the polygon in the wrong place.

The PolygonShape Class

```
class PolygonShape {

   int x, y;
   private Polygon p;

   public PolygonShape(int x, int y) {
    // the x, y sent to this constructor
    //are the cordinates of the point where the user clicked
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;       
   }

   public void draw(Graphics g) {       
    p = new Polygon();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      p.addPoint((int) (x + y * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / 5)),
          (int) (x + y * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / 5)));
    g.drawPolygon(p);       
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't draw a polygon or is the polygon in the wrong place?

Comment: It draws the polygon in the wrong place

Comment: the p.addPoint parameters in your draw method look really weird. For both x and y, you take the variable x + (y * something random). I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that, but are you sure it's correct?

Comment: You are right, the problem is that i want to get the right formula of the equation you pointed to, any help?

Comment: So basically your question becomes "how do I calculate the points in a 5-point polygon?". I'm afraid I'm not that much of a math wiz.

Comment: Me too, anyways thanks for your time.

Comment: Assuming `x` and `y` are the center of the polygon, you're using them wrong (you need to add x to the x coordinate and y to the y coordinate) and you're missing another important variable: `r` for radius; instead of multiplying by `y`, you should multiply by `r` in your formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `x` and `y` are the center of the polygon, you're using them wrong (you need to add `x` to the x coordinate and `y` to the y coordinate) and you're missing another important variable: `r` for radius. Instead of multiplying by `y`, you should multiply by `r` in your formulae.

In other words:

```
class PolygonShape {

    int x, y, r;
    private Polygon p;

    public PolygonShape(int x, int y, int r) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;       
    }

    // Provide a default radius of 100 pixels if no radius is given.
    public PolygonShape(int x, int y) {
        this(x, y, 100);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {       
        p = new Polygon();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            double angle = i * 2 * Math.PI / 5;
            p.addPoint((int) (x + r * Math.cos(angle)),
                       (int) (y + r * Math.sin(angle)));
        }
        g.drawPolygon(p); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set the translation on the graphics before drawing:

```
final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
g2.translate(x, y);
g2.drawPolygon(p);
```

You may need to do `-x, -y`, you'll have to try it.

I am working on a new graphics object (`g2`) so that the translate is not permanent.

Advantage is, can draw same shape in multiple places, just vary `x` and `y`.